# b-form-timepicker prevent closing when clicked outside

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to prevent b-form-timepicker from closing when I edit other input field. I combined b-form-timepicker with b-form-input as shown:

```
<b-input-group>
  <b-form-input 
    v-model="item.endTime" 
    type="text"
   ></b-form-input>
  <b-input-group-append>
    <b-form-timepicker 
      v-model="item.endTime" 
      button-only
    ></b-form-timepicker>
  </b-input-group-append>
</b-input-group>
```

How can I keep the time picker opened while I edit the input?